# overriding the format of 'copy-as' latex?

Tags: latex

In the answer to [Bold face formatting for vectors instead of overarrows like latex \mathbf{}?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2248/bold-face-formatting-for-vectors-instead-of-overarrows-like-latex-mathbf/2269#2269) was a nice method of specifying the visual display for a variable, so that I can do something like the following to generate display output for vectors in the way that I want it:

```
Clear[vecX]
Format[boldVector[v_]] := Style[HoldForm[v], FontFamily -> "Arial Black"]
vecX := boldVector[x]
Abs[vecX - vecX'] // TraditionalForm
```

Is there a way to specify how text in copy-as Latex should appear?  For example, if I could do copy-as latex and have `vecX` above show up as `\vecX`, then I can have my latex macros deal with the formatting in that context:

```
\newcommand{\vecX}[0]{\mathbf{x}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to do this automatically on *Copy as LaTeX*.  I also do not know enough about LaTeX to know the right way to make changes.

I should point out that `vecX` no longer appears in the output of `Abs[vecX - vecX'] // TraditionalForm` therefore you must base your output on `boldVector[x]` and not `vecX`, unless you want to work with a held expression, which I imagine you do not.

The best I can recommend is using your own convert-to-LaTeX function something like this:

```
myTeX =
 StringReplace[
   ToString @ TeXForm[# /. boldVector -> bvTeX], 
   "text{bvTeX}" :> "EXAMPLE"
 ] &;

Abs[vecX - vecX'] // myTeX
```

> ```
> \left|\EXAMPLE(x)-\EXAMPLE(x)'\right|
> ```

I am sure this is gibberish.  I simply want to show how this may be approached.

Comment: I wonder if TeXForm can be extended (maybe with Format, which is assignable) ...

Comment: @Szabolcs I wonder too, because I don't know how.