# TeXForm for bold symbols and cells

Tags: formatting, latex

I would like to get the following equation in TeXForm

[image]

Here **y**(t), **G** and **F**  are vectors and are in bold. If I do

```
TeXForm[HoldForm[y''[t] + G[y'[t], y[t]] == F[t]]]
```

in an Input Cell I get the correct TeX but not with the appropriate symbols in bold. The required equation is set up in a `TradionalForm` cell with the correct bold symbols. However, I don't seem to be able to export this to TeX. Is this possible or is there another work around?
Possibly [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2248/12558) answer is relevant.

Comment: How have you set up the bold symbols in TraditionalForm?

Comment: In a TraditionalForm cell everything is automatically in bold. I you don' want bold then you have to  un-bold the symbol. However in an input cell it is difficult to make a bold symbol. My thinking was that you could try and convert a TraditionalForm Cell to TeX.

Answer (score 0):

See TeXForm help. No Mathematica format boxes are translated, only single character symbols as italics and word symbols as \text{} boxes are used in translation.

This yields a possibility to modify an expressions TeXForm, as a string,  e.g. by

```
 raw = "$$" <> ToString[TeXForm[y''[x] == Sin[x]]] <> "$$" 

  bold = StringReplace[raw, "y" -> "\\mathbf{y}"]
```

$$\mathbf{y}''(x)=\sin (x)$$

```
     Import[ StringToStream[bold], "LaTeX" ]  




Notebook[{Cell[TextData[{}], "Text"], 
   Cell[BoxData[FormBox[RowBox[{SuperscriptBox[StyleBox["y",
   FontSlant -> "Bold"],"\[Prime]\[Prime]"], 
   RowBox[{"(", StyleBox["x", "TI"], ")"}],"\[LongEqual]", "sin", 
   RowBox[{"(", StyleBox["x", "TI"], ")"}]}], TraditionalForm]],
   "NumberedEquation"]}, StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a replacement rule for the example you posted. For each of these rules, the lhs is a Mathematica expression and the rhs is the styled string you want to see in the TeX, representing that expression.

```
TeXForm[HoldForm[y''[t] + G[y'[t], y[t]] == F[t]]]
```

(* y''(t)+G\left(y'(t),y(t)\right)=F(t) *)

This is basically just a string. Now just replace G,y,F with Style[_,Bold]:

```
%2 /. {G -> Style["G", Bold], y -> Style["y", Bold], 
  F -> Style["F", Bold]}
```

(It doesn't render well in the browser so I'll post a screenshot.)
[image]

If you also want to use bold type for the "primes" on the derivatives, you need to write a pattern which matches the derivative operator in the code. In this case, the nth derivative is Derivative[n][y][t]. Since you're mapping to a string, each 'n' must be written separately. To get the arguments in normal weight, use a second "Text" style box for each "[t]".

```
%2 /. {G -> Style["G", Bold], y -> Style["y", Bold], 
  F -> Style["F", Bold], 
  Derivative[1][y][t] :> Style["y'", Bold] Style["[t]", "Text"], 
  Derivative[2][y][t] :> Style["y''", Bold] Style["[t]", "Text"]}
```

[image]